# Operator used tempdb to spill data, spill level 1

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb, query-performance

Here I have a query which is spilling to tempdb.

[image]

I understand that the cardinality estimates are wrong and causing this spill. I've read few articles that mentions updating the statistics and rebuilding the indexes. I've done the update statistics with full scan along with rebuilding the index then I cleared the cache on my test environment but the query is still spilling to tempdb.

What else can I do? Help me please!! The query is being used heavily daily, it is not very heavy but it is being used a lot and it is hammering the tempdb...

[Query plan](https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bki7JxRFr)

Available indexes on table Register_event_details_slts:

```
/****** Object:  Index [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLTS_PK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:49 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLTS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_BEHAVIOUR_ID_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:50 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_BEHAVIOUR_ID_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [ASSOCIATED_BEHAVIOUR_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_CONT_STAT_ID_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:50 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_CONT_STAT_ID_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [CONTRACT_STATUS_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_CONTRACTS_ID_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:51 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_CONTRACTS_ID_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [CONTRACT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I1]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:51 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I1] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAIL_ID] ASC,
    [PLANNED_START_DATE] ASC,
    [PLANNED_END_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I2]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:53 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I2] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [OBJECT_ID] ASC,
    [OBJECT_TYPE] ASC,
    [PLANNED_START_DATE] ASC,
    [PLANNED_END_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I3]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:54 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_I3] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [ACTUAL_START_DATE] ASC,
    [ACTUAL_END_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_R_EVENT_ID_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:54 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_R_EVENT_ID_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [REGISTER_EVENT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_R_EVT_SLT_ID_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:55 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_R_EVT_SLT_ID_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [REGISTER_EVENT_SLOT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_SESS_COD_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:55 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_SESS_COD_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [SESSION_CODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [R_EVT_DET_SLT_USAGE_OBJ_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:56 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R_EVT_DET_SLT_USAGE_OBJ_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [USAGE_CODE] ASC,
    [OBJECT_TYPE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS_FOREMA]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:56 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS_FOREMA] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [OBJECT_TYPE] ASC,
    [OBJECT_ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([REGISTER_EVENT_ID],[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAIL_ID],[REGISTER_EVENT_SLOT_ID],[USAGE_CODE]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLTS_I1]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:57 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLTS_I1] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [OBJECT_TYPE] ASC
)
INCLUDE([REGISTER_EVENT_DETAIL_ID],[OBJECT_ID],[PLANNED_START_DATE],[PLANNED_END_DATE],[REGISTER_EVENT_SLOT_ID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [RGSTR_VNT_DTLS_SLTS_IC_FK]    Script Date: 24/10/2019 12:27:58 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RGSTR_VNT_DTLS_SLTS_IC_FK] ON [dbo].[REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS]
(
    [INSTITUTION_CONTEXT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Can you [post](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) the execution plan?

Comment: Hi Kevin, i have added an image, couldn't figure how to add .XML or plan files.

Comment: Save the execution plan to a file, open that file in notepad or whatever text editor you have available, and then upload the raw XML to [https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).  Post the generated link here.

Comment: Hi John, this is the plan. Thank you
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bki7JxRFr

Comment: Done, Query plan link added to the question.

Comment: Worth reading:  [why should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: @mustaccio thank you, Noted. I'm totally new to this.

Comment: Still waiting an answer, come on community please!!

Comment: It's unlikely you will get a very precise cardinality estimate with a non-deterministic function in a range predicate like your `planned_start_date >= dateadd(hh,-2,getdate())  and  planned_start_date <= getdate() +7`. You cannot avoid the sort either. Get flash storage for your tempdb maybe?

Comment: Hi @mustaccio , its not the date function, i have replaced the last condition with
and planned_start_date >= '20191024'  and  planned_start_date <= '20191031'
and still getting the spill.
What do you mean by flash storage for tempdb?

Comment: Are you sure tempdb is the big problem here? Writing 13 pages isn't *that* much unless the query is being called many times in a short period. The fact that it is index scanning to filter on room code and needing to seek in REGISTER_EVENT_DETAILS_SLOTS 660 times might be more significant. Is there no useful index for that filtering to use? It would be a good idea to add to the question what indexes exist on the relevant tables, so we know what options the query planner had available to select from.

Comment: Hi @DavidSpillett, the query is not expensive but its being used more than 50 times a minute as it retrieves the timetable for the students. My server CPU utilization jumps to 80% continuously if i turn that query back on. I have found another solution for the application that was calling it but im keen to learn what was causing this spill.
I have attached all the indexes on that table.